# Wordpress Facebook Comment Counter PHP

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to display the Facebook comment count on my blog archives.

My wordpress site has the following php function in function.php

```
        // Get combined FB and WordPress comment count
        function full_comment_count() {
        global $post;
        $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

        $filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
        $json = json_decode($filecontent);
        $count = $json->$url->comments;
        $wpCount = get_comments_number();
        $realCount = $count + $wpCount;
        if ($realCount == 0 || !isset($realCount)) {
            $realCount = 0;
        }
        return $realCount;
        }
```

When I go to use the function `<?php echo full_comment_count(); ?>`

There is a value returned '0'... THIS WAS WORKING. But suddenly does not work. You can see this problem  [here](http://www.womenoffaith.com) in the blog area... it seems like there was a change in the URL `https://graph.facebook.com/?ids={your url}`.... It may have something to do with HTML5... ?

Comment: Looks like it's working for me: http://www.womenoffaith.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

It works. I didnt do anything... I just checked back a few hours later and it was working.